# Can't write the flac file into speech google server in java

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I'm studying a simple application "speech to text" via [Google Speech API v2](https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2). I have made a Java project and downloaded a flac file (`good-morning-google.flac`) to test it.

When I send the flac file to the google server, I get the following error:

> java.io.IOException: Error writing to server Finished     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseMessage(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseMessage(Unknown
>   Source)   at speech.JavaSoundRecorder.main(JavaSoundRecorder.java:140)

I think that the problem is in the definition of the url, but I'm not sure. Could anybody help me to resolve it?

This is my code to connect to google server:

```
    String urlString = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-US&" + key;
    try {
    url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(60000);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-flac;rate=44100");

    /*Write the audio on bufferI/O*/
    File file = new File("C:/Travail/audio/good-morning-google.flac");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    fis.read(buffer);
    fis.close();
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(buffer);
    os.close();

    connection.connect();
    System.out.println("connect to google server!");
    connection.getResponseMessage();
    System.out.println("receive the reponse!");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
      }
      System.out.println(stringBuilder);
     // JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: did you miss a `try {` in the beginning ?

Comment: Hi mlwn, here I have one try block with two catches blocks, I think it isn't the problem.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555322/multiple-or-single-try-catch)

Answer (score 0):

first use CURL to post the flac file.

Then, inspect the http headers coming from your "connection" in java to see that they match the curl...

If they are pretty close then the java post should also work.

[curl sample](http://pastebin.com/eNkpfwbk)

Answer (score 0):

you missed `&key=` before "+ key" in the definition of you URL