# Is it possible to have multiple tries, with only one catch

Tags: java, exception

I'm adding multiple players to a team and each individual player needs a try catch, but the catch is always the same

```
try{
    team.addPlayer( new Player( 1, "PLYR1" ) );
} catch ( Exception e ){
     System.out.println( e.toString() );
}

try {
     team.addPlayer( new Player( 2, "PLYR2" ) );
} catch ( Exception e ){
     System.out.println( e.toString() );
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: You can add the players in the same `try` clause, and have only one `catch`.

Comment: The answer is yes, but the exact way you would do it depends on what behaviour you want. For example, if adding player 1 fails do you want to try adding player 2 or do you want to stop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple or Single Try Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555322/multiple-or-single-try-catch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate through all possible `players` using catch and throw the same error to `stdout` if an exception occurs you should use a basic for loop.

`Player` class is assumed to be defined and `team` object created:

```
String[] players = {"PLYR1", "PLYR2", "PLYR3"}

for (String player: players) {
  try{
      team.addPlayer( new Player( 1, player ) );
  } catch ( Exception e ){
       System.out.println( e.toString() );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as saying at your comments you can use this

```
try{
    team.addPlayer( new Player( 1, "PLYR1" ) );
    team.addPlayer( new Player( 2, "PLYR2" ) );
} catch ( Exception e ){
     System.out.println( e.toString() );
}
```

of if you care about if the first player is added, use this:

```
try{
    team.addPlayer( new Player( 1, "PLYR1" ) );
    try {
         team.addPlayer( new Player( 2, "PLYR2" ) );
    } catch ( Exception e ){
         System.out.println( e.toString() );
    }
} catch ( Exception e ){
     System.out.println( e.toString() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code instead of using two try blocks.

```
try{
    team.addPlayer( new Player( 1, "PLYR1" ) );
     team.addPlayer( new Player( 2, "PLYR2" ) );
} 
catch ( Exception e ){
     System.out.println( e.toString() );
}
```