# javascript multiple try catch

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I read this article [Multiple try-catch or one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239906/multiple-try-catch-or-one) and was wondering if there was a better way? Is there a way to just ignore the bad lines of code? My problem is I need to load multiple variables from objects that may or may not exist.
Thanks everyone

```js
 toparcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[425]")[0].value;
  toparcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[423]")[0].value;
  toparcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[424]")[0].value;
  toparcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[426]")[0].value;
  toparcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[434]")[0].value;
  bottomarcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[271]")[0].value;
  bottomarcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[265]")[0].value;
  bottomarcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[268]")[0].value;
  bottomarcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[369]")[0].value;
  bottomarcv = document.getElementsByName("attribute[433]")[0].value;
console.log(toparcv);
console.log(bottomarcv);
```

im trying to read a textbox from a website that randomly generates the name from about 10 different names by adding 433 or 268.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an `if` statement to check that the object exists.

Comment: Put `try/catch` just around the code that throws the exception, instead of the whole block.

Comment: Maybe you should be using a loop or function so you don't need to repeat code for each variable.

Comment: the if statement would have like 15 if else's or am i nuts?

Comment: good idea on the loop maybe i can do that

Comment: @zackmcdonald - can you provide some code showing exactly what it is you are trying to do, or an example?  It seems like maybe you've got a problem that's easily solved but you're just going down the wrong path with the `try...catch` stuff...

Comment: I agree with anied.  If you show us an exact example of what you're trying to do, we can help you much, much more specifically.  You have proposed [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're asking questions about your proposed solution rather than explaining the problem and letting us offer the best solution.

Comment: i cant put try catch around the whole code, it will end the code after the first bad line

Answer (score 0):

You can cover all the `bottommarcv` assignments like this:

```
[271, 265, 268, 369, 433].forEach(function(num) {
    var list = document.getElementsByName("attribute[" + num + "]");
    if (list && list.length) {
        bottomarcv = list[0].value;
    }
});
```

This code pre-preemptively avoids an exception by checking the integrity of variables before referencing properties on them and because it's using a loop to examine each element, it can use only one `if` statement for all the values.

It is a little odd to be assigning them all to the same variable.  Do you really only want the last one that has a value to be used here?

Comment: @zackmcdonald - You will have to show us exactly what code you are using because I don't think the code in my answer can generate that error.  If `list` is `undefined`, then the code will not evaluate `list.length` at all.  Please check to make sure you have the code the same as I show it.

Comment: @zackmcdonald - Did this work for you once you corrected your code?